# Windows Delete File On Shutdown

Tags: windows, file, delete-file, shutdown

I'm trying to make a uninstaller for my software. When the user wants to delete my software uninstaller.exe runs and deletes all the files and registries. But How I am going to delete uninstaller.exe ? I thought windows has an api for delete file on shutdown or something like that. BTW I have already tried a .bat files to delete uninstaller.exe but it is located in program files so UAC is a problem for that.

Answer (score 1):

[MoveFileEx() (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365240%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) does the trick. Set `lpNewFileName` to null and the file will be deleted instead of renamed.